# Does everyone have plantuml in markdown files in a bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, plantuml

I have a lot of plantuml stuff in project markdown files and it works pretty good with gitlab. Now I have to migrate to bitbucket and it seems there is no free solutions to enable plantuml pictures into the documentation.

Has everyone figured out how plantuml previews could be enabled into bitbucket?

Answer (score 7):

After some research I found a solution that could work without additional plugins.
The approach:

1. Install your own plantuml-server (described here:
   https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server)
2. put your plantuml files as text files into your bitbucket repository
3. include the plantuml diagrams as images into your markdown files. The image 
   source points to your plantuml-server with the built-in proxy parameter 
   (described here: http://plantuml.com/server)

```
# example mark down
![my diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/schlothauer-wauer/jsoncodegen/master/docs/main_structure.puml)
```

The referenced puml has to be published accessible

Comment: Do you have a live example?